# Running web browser inside WPF app?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, architecture

I have a WPF application that interacts with audio hardware on the machine that I am looking to add new features to.  A lot of the features that I am looking to add (chat support, social networking, etc.) are all things that can be easily handled with AngularJS, SignalR, and other various web app tools.  I'm trying to figure out if I can program these features as a web app and can this inside my WPF app.  A few things need to happen:

- User authenticates with website & receives ASP.net forms auth cookie
- User is taken to web app
- Web app contains hyperlinks that are recognized by WPF app & allow the app to interact with audio hardware on the computer.

With Silverlight out of the picture I'm not sure if there's a better way to interact with hardware.  Am I better off doing away with the whole 'web app' concept and build everything inside WPF?  Eventually this will need to be cross platform, which also seems to favor the web app.

Comment: Are you looking for embeding WebBrowser into WPF or running a web interface accessible from outside the WPF application ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to provide a web application (REST or more) distributed from/by your WPF application I can recommand you [NancyFX](http://nancyfx.org/) which is easy to handle and to add features to fit you needs.

You can that way create a HTTP listener to a port, and provide links that are related to that web service (and handle the correct behavior in the application).